# Extract url from text file

Tags: html, powershell, url, text-parsing

I have a large text file that contains the text View this email in your browser then a URL. It can vary and sometimes part of the URL goes onto the next line.

Also, when it does go onto the next line there is an equals symbol at the end which needs to be removed but not any other equals symbols which may be there.

Few examples:

```
View this email in your browser (https://us15.campaign-archive.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6e2bb1612577510b&id=3D2c8be)

View this email in your browser <https://mail.com/?e=3D14=
60&u=3Df612577510b&id=3D2c8be>

View this email in your browser (https://eg.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6510b&id=3D2c8be)
```

I need to extract that URL using PowerShell, without the brackets (parentheses), which sometimes can be < > so that I can download it as a HTML file.

```
 if ($str -match '(?<=\()https?://[^)]+') {
 #  # ... remove any line breaks from it, and output the result.
  $Matches.0 -replace '\r?\n'
 }

 if ($str -match '(?<=\<)https?://[^>]+') {
 #  # ... remove any line breaks from it, and output the result.
  $Matches.0 -replace '\r?\n'
 }
```

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? All example URLs seem to be [matched without any problems](https://tio.run/##zZLdT8IwFMXf91ecAGFblMFQwBg@XnzUxPj1Ahi6cWGNW7e0HQsx/u3YETUkojFqjEkfbnua@zv3tFlakFQRxfFms8hFqHkqsCR9e3WuHBePVsYkS@BYwPiyLEmTdNwpxtdacrGcoqa0tFyj8wWccoNGwnQYwXZG/cHEcSOtMzU6bTbH9@70wC6bAtVyeZ4HSUm6IjCxRswFIZDEHhQWMk3A9aER5khzneUaOiJzXeWx9kwHoHZRckh5LTQkZTELCfZEjibCNvqT9aGn/q6n4Z96Mq5e0kXljlNhGnAFShiPwQXWaS4NLi0USThbl8ZkrvyOF7IkY3wpGkyGEV@RF6ZJc0SDozP/uNuq56ZYdKkdBH7Xb3d6vY7fCup8bo7b4UlAbuXr4P4ruFR3OQO8kfYxhpVvDEfLvZO8t1/FjQlbmS@ILSIw8RdcR2AQVGwfykDMg0j6ScYz8b9Snonfz3kmPkt6s3kG)

Comment: They match but there is the equals symbol problem at the end of the lines if they go over multiple lines

Comment: Also its got additional spaces in the middle of the url and some ` symbols in there as well which means the url isnt valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you're trying to match *across lines*, you need to make sure that your text file is read *as a whole*, i.e. as a single, multiline string, which you can do with the `-Raw` switch of the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) cmdlet.
- Apart from that, the only thing missing from your regex was to also match and remove a preceding `=` before newlines.

The following extracts all URLs from input file `file.txt`, and outputs them - with the newline and line-ending `=` removed - as an array of strings:

```bash
# Note the '=' before '\r?\n'
[regex]::Matches(
  (Get-Content -Raw file.txt),
  '(?<=[<(])https://[^>)]+'
).Value -replace '=\r?\n'
```

- Direct use of the [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) .NET API allows you to extract *all* matches at once, whereas PowerShell's [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator only ever looks for *one* match.

  - See [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) for a proposal to introduce a `-matchall` operator in the future.
- [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is then used to remove newlines (`\r?\n`) from the matches, along with a preceding `=`.

For an explanation of the URL-matching regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/a4QYbG/1).

---

Example with a multiline string literal:

```bash
[regex]::Matches('
View this email in your browser (https://us15.campaign-archive.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6e2bb1612577510b&id=3D2c8be)

View this email in your browser <https://mail.com/?e=3D14=
60&u=3Df612577510b&id=3D2c8be>

View this email in your browser (https://eg.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6510b&id=3D2c8be)
  ',
  '(?<=[<(])https://[^>)]+'
).Value -replace '=\r?\n'
```

Output:

```
https://us15.campaign-archive.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6e2bb1612577510b&id=3D2c8be
https://mail.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df612577510b&id=3D2c8be
https://eg.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6510b&id=3D2c8be
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for the examples you provided:

```
    $text = @(
    'View this email in your browser (https://us15.campaign-archive.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6e2bb1612577510b&id=3D2c8be)',
    'View this email in your browser <https://mail.com/?e=3D14=
60&u=3Df612577510b&id=3D2c8be>',
    'View this email in your browser (https://eg.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6510b&id=3D2c8be)'
)

$text = $text | ForEach-Object {
    $PSItem.Replace('<','(').Replace('>',')').Replace("=`n",'').Split('(')[1].Replace(')','')
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
https://us15.campaign-archive.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6e2bb1612577510b&id=3D2c8be
https://mail.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df612577510b&id=3D2c8be
https://eg.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6510b&id=3D2c8be
```

I simply use replace without regex.
The part where you struggled with the split url is solved by doing

```
.Replace("=`n")
```

Comment: Thanks but will that find the url in the text file?

Comment: Send a sample of the text file. Then I can tell you.

Comment: Avoiding regexes is warranted where a conceptually clearer solution is available, but your answer doesn't strike me as an example of that. Also note that Coder's own attempt uses regex `\r?\n` to match newlines in either Windows or Unix format; using a literal replacement with just ``"`n"`` (`\n` in regex terms) isn't equivalent.